# How can I limit the bandwidth used by a process?

Tags: centos, networking, bandwidth

I have a CentOS 5.7 server that will be backing up its files nightly. I am concerned that visitors to the various sites that the server hosts will experience degraded performance while the backup is transferring across the network.

Is it possible to limit a process's maximum allowed throughput to a network interface? I would like to limit the SSH-based file transfer to only half of my available bandwidth. This could be on the server or client side; that is, I'd be happy to do this on either the client that initiates the connection or the server that receives the connection.

<sub>(Unfortunately, I can't add an interface to dedicate to backups. I could increase my available throughput, but that would merely mean that the network transfer would complete faster, but still max the total capacity of the connection while doing it.)</sub>

---

### Some Background

Perhaps some background is in order. Stepping back, I had a problem with not having enough local space to create the backup itself. Enter SSHFS! The backup is saved to what is ostensibly a local drive so that no backup bits are ever on the web server itself.

Why is that important? Because that would seem to invalidate the use of the venerable `rsync --bwlimit`. `rsync` isn't actually doing the transfer nor **can** it because I can't even spare the space to save the backup file.

I can hear you ask: "So wait, why do you even need to make a backup file? Why not just `rsync` the source files and folders?" Because an annoying thing called "Plesk" is in the mix! This is my client-facing web host which uses Plesk for convenience. As such, I use Plesk to initiate the backups because Plesk adds all sorts of extra magic to the backup that makes consuming it during a restoration procedure very safe.

*sad face*

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth

Comment: Another possibility for my situation, which incidentally doesn't *exactly* answer the specific question, is to use `ionice` to throttle the writes that a process can make. Since I'm writing to an SSHFS filesystem, I can drop the class of the backup process to 3 to make it completely give way to any other process that wants to write. That way I get the effect that I want which is to never degrade a site visitor's experience because of the backup hogging bandwidth.

Comment: One question, your ssh uses compression? "Compression yes" to your .ssh/config?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `iptables` to mark a packet (--pid-owner ...), then use `tc` to shape the traffic.
Also "--sid-owner" can be used to include threads and children of that process.

http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#OWNERMATCH

> **Match**  --pid-owner
>   **Kernel** 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6
>   **Example**    iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --pid-owner 78
>   **Explanation**    This match is used to match packets based on the Process ID (PID) that was responsible for them. This match is a bit harder to use, but one example would be only to allow PID 94 to send packets from the HTTP port (if the HTTP process is not threaded, of course). Alternatively we could write a small script that grabs the PID from a ps output for a specific daemon and then adds a rule for it. For an example, you could have a rule as shown in the Pid-owner.txt example

Comment: I think this ties with my solution for the best way to do this. --pid-owner doesn't actually select based on the process, but the process owner. I'd have to create a special user to launch the process as and then filter based on that owner just so I can be sure I'm shaping traffic just from that specific process and not, say, multiple daemons that might have been launched from a generic user.

Comment: @Wesley That's not what the man page says: "`--pid-owner processid`
Matches if the packet was **created by a process with the given process id**." http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: This answer would be much better if it included an example of how to use iptables and tc for this purpose. The given `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --pid-owner 78` example doesn't seem to be complete (as it only matches packets, it doesn't say how to "mark" them) and `tc` isn't explained at all.

Comment: To mark a packet you need to add something like `-j MARK --set-mark 1`. For more details see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_traffic_control#Using_tc_.2B_iptables

Comment: Instead of `iptables`, it's possible to use `cgroups` with `net_cls` classifier: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328349/1254

Answer (score 55):

One option that I just discovered is to use [`trickle`](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle).

> `trickle` is a portable lightweight userspace bandwidth shaper. It can run in collaborative mode (together with `trickled`) or in stand alone mode.
>
> `trickle` works by taking advantage of the Unix loader preloading. Essentially it provides, to the application, a new version of the functionality that is required to send and receive data through sockets. It then limits traffic based on delaying the sending and receiving of data over a socket. `trickle` runs entirely in userspace and does not require root privileges.

For Ubuntu users, install it by running

```shell
sudo apt install trickle
```

And as an example, run `maven build` while limiting it to 20kB/s download rate and 111kB/s for upload:

```shell
trickle -sd 20 -u 111 mvn build
```

Comment: This is the one that solved my problem. I was having a problem with the bitcoin daemon randomly sucking all my bandwdith when a client decided that I was the person they should download the whole blockchain from.

Comment: or `sudo apt-get install trickle`

Comment: trickle doesn't always work though... rtfm for more details

Answer (score 24):

If you can write to a pipe (or stdout), you can install the `pv` (pipe viewer) command. It was originally written to display the progress of data transferred through a pipe.

`tar cvf - /files/to/backup | pv -L 512k > /your/file/on/sshfs`

```
   -L RATE, --rate-limit RATE
          Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE  bytes  per  second.   A
          suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes
          (*1024), megabytes, and so on.
```

Comment: This is actually the answer I think I'll use! However, it's not exactly an answer to the specific question I originally asked. Alas, the question kind of morphed but was still focused on limiting the network speed of a process. However, you can contribute to this new question I asked: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34174/4232

Comment: Thanks! I was doing a similar thing and ended up doing `ssh my-remote-server bash -c "'find / -xdev|cpio -o|gzip -c1'"|pv --rate-limit 1M > my-remote-root.cpio.gz`.

Comment: Could have combined it with ionice as well, but it wasn't allowed on that particular server. `ssh my-remote-server ionice -c3 bash -c "'find / -xdev|cpio -o|gzip -c1'"|pv --rate-limit 1M > my-remote-root.cpio.gz`

Answer (score 8):

I use rsync with the --bwlimit=KBPS option for the same reason.

Our 1 Gbit ethernet is easily able to swamp our old SCSI320 DAS RAID, and essentially DOS's some our older production boxes that rely on it for its NFS stores.

Answer (score 4):

How are you transferring the data? (rsync over ssh? scp? sftp? something else?)

rsync will allow you to limit bandwidth (see the option --bwlimit=KBPS).
rsync -e ssh --bwlimit ..

Alternatively, you could setup a qdisc or equivalent to do fancy rate limiting, but I suspect that in your case this would be severe overkill.
Documentation on this is available at [The Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.lartc.org)