# How can I limit the output speed of stdout?

Tags: hard-disk, io, stdout

I'm running CentOS 5.7 and I have a backup utility that has the option of dumping its backup file to `stdout`. The backup file is rather large (multiple gigabytes). The target is an SSHFS filesystem. To ensure that I don't hog the bandwidth and degrade the performance of the network, I would like to limit the speed with which data is written to the "disk".

How can I limit the ability of `stdout` based on a byte number? For example, limiting a process's ability to write to about 768Bps.

Comment: @msw this question is about rate-limiting `stdout`, the previous question was about limiting network traffic.  Different beasts...

Comment: @msw Last I checked, the point of the SE network is to collect a massive amount of knowledge in specific areas. In this case, it's about *nix. Limiting the output of `stdout` is different than limiting bandwidth. Just because the underlying problem is the same doesn't mean that future visitors won't find each question useful independent of the other. Remember that the Qs&As are just as much for googlers as for the actual askers, which is why deleting answered questions is such a cardinal sin here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add a rate limiting tool to your pipeline.

For example there is [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) which has a rate-limiting option:

> ```
> -L RATE, --rate-limit RATE
> ```
>
> Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE bytes per second.  A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or  "t"  can  be  added  to  denote  kilobytes  (*1024), megabytes, and so on

An alternative is the tool [`buffer`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/buffer) which has:

> ```
>    -u microseconds
> ```
>
> After every write pause for this many microseconds.  Defaults to zero.  (Surprisingly a small sleep, 100 usecs, after  each  write  can  greatly 
>   enhance throughput on some drives.)

Answer (score 3):

I would be tempted to dump this on a local disk instead of writing it directly to the remote volume. This way you can use `rsync` with `--bwlimit` to easily limit the transfer.

One of the benefits to this approach is that if there is a connectivity hiccup to the remote machine, the transfer is interrupted, but the backup itself doesn't explode in a blaze of glory.

Comment: Noted. I do so wish that `rsync` was a viable solution in this rather limited situation I find myself in. =|

Answer (score 3):

pv (pipe view)

```
echo asdlfkjasdf | pv -q -L 12
```