# limit stdout to terminal output speed

Tags: terminal, tail, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I limit the output speed of stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/how-can-i-limit-the-output-speed-of-stdout)

What's the easiest way to limit the speed at which stdout is output in a terminal, so that, for instance, `tail -f` outputs content at the speed at which a human could read it?

I've tried changing the output baud rate of the current terminal (`stty -F $(tty) ospeed 110`), but the output still seems to be a the same speed.

I've tried sending it trough `pv -L`, but it garbles the output.

Comment: Pipe it through `less`

Comment: @Kevin, that (almost) works, the issue is I'm looking for something that scrolls on its own. Also, I'm piping the output trough `ccze` (colorizer) and calling `less -R` afterwards messes up the ouptut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a program called `pv` which can do rate limiting.

```
pv -q -L RATE
```

The `-q` is for `--quiet` mode, which shouldn't garble output.