# How do I throttle the redirection > /dev/null in linux?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm using bash command XXX > /dev/null to simulate a remote ssh session the runs XXX, but it is too fast for the purpose.

Can I slow it down by adding a throttle to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit the output speed of stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/how-can-i-limit-the-output-speed-of-stdout)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to slow down? Some sort of output?