# Why doesn't rate limiting with trickle work with ruby?

Tags: linux, networking, ruby

I'm attempting to limit the bandwidth available to a running ruby process to prevent it flooding our link and affecting other traffic. The process is downloading large files over HTTP.

I've found numerous people suggesting `trickle` as a convenient userland-only option (like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34123/160146).

I've tested it with an scp download and confirmed it limits the download rate:

```
trickle -s -d 50 scp user@example.com localfile.dat
```

I've also tested a python 2.7 script and confirmed it limits the download rate:

```
# cat test.py
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://example.com/bigfile.dat")
# trickle -s -d 50 python test.py
```

Finally, I've tested with a basic ruby script and trickle has no effect. The scripts maxes out my downstream bandwidth:

```
# cat test.rb 
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://example.com/bigfile.dat"))
# trickle -s -d 50 ruby test.rb
```

I've tested with ruby 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 with no difference in behaviour.

I notice the trickle documentation says it only works with dynamically linked programs, but I'm fairly sure thats the case for me. I'm using the ruby provided by Debian in `/usr/bin`, and `ldd` reports linked libraries:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/ruby2.3 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffdcdc6000)
        libruby-2.3.so.2.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.3.so.2.3 (0x00007f277e11a000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f277defd000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f277dc79000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f277da75000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f277d83e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f277d538000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f277d194000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558796396000)
```

Interestingly, trickle can rate limit my ruby process if I use the curb (libcurl bindings) gem:

```
# cat test.rb
require 'curb'
http = Curl.get("http://example.com/bigfile.dat"))
# trickle -s -d 50 ruby test.rb
```

Does that suggest that ruby's default `Net::HTTP` library uses sockets in a way that's incompatible with trickle?

I'm out of ideas. Is there a fixed reason why trickle doesn't work with ruby or is there something I can do to get them working together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've tracked this down. It's arguably a fault in `trickle` that's occurred as a result of *creeping featurism* in the `socket()` library call.

The `trickle` code redefines `socket()`, as you know. At the top of its reimplementation in the file `trickle-overload.c` it has a check that includes `type == SOCK_STREAM` so that only connections of type `SOCK_STREAM` are eligible for processing.

The `ruby` code opens the socket with `type = SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC`. The `SOCK_CLOEXEC` is a Linux extension (since 2.6.27) that avoids the use of a subsequent `fcntl` call to set the close-on-exec flag.

Unfortunately `SOCK_STREAM` is not the same as `SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC` so the `trickle` processing will not take place until its code is fixed to allow for the extensions now permitted within `socket`'s `type` field.

I know of no workaround other than to recompile `trickle` for your system with a modified socket type comparison.

(I've submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824513) to Debian Bugs since that's my preferred platform.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research - I definitely wouldn't have tracked this down. Debian is my preferred platform too - hopefully your bug report prompts a change