# How can I limit Download bandwidth of an existing process? (iptables, tc, ?)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tc, packet

I am happily limiting upload speed by port - but really want to limit download by process.

It seems iptables did have functionality for matching and marking packets by process in the form of `--pid-owner` or `--cmd-owner` - but both have now been removed?

```
$ iptables -m owner --help
...
owner match options:
[!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]      Match local UID
[!] --gid-owner groupid[-groupid]    Match local GID
[!] --socket-exists                  Match if socket exists
```

seems there are options to match by user or group, but not process.

I am aware of trickle, and wondershaper - but neither allow shaping of an already running process

Comment: one end of the connection will probably have a "random" port number, perhaps you can use that port-number for shaping.

Comment: [Related (and maybe duplicate?)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-a-process)

Comment: @Ikaros nope - the accepted answer --pid-owner or --cwd-owner has been removed from iptables, followed by trickle, which cannot limit an already rnning process

Comment: You are right, no problem then :)

Comment: @Ikaros I'd seen it before writing this question, and intended to limit it - but somehow did not (will do next time)

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @rraallvv Not exactly. I started writing a solution. https://github.com/chozabu/LinNetLim IIRC I got it working to limit upload, but not download reliably

Comment: From what I've found in random post, it seems there is no reliable way to limit downloads. Maybe because packages have already arrived, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @rraallvv I think there is - netlimiter on windows seems to manage fairly well, as does "trickle" on Linux (but the limited process must be launched via trickle). With TCP discarding some incoming packets may be enough to slow down the send rate. Not sure though, and very unsure about UDP!

Comment: Seems this is indeed the case with TCP https://serverfault.com/a/336292/389774

Answer (score 5):

Put the process into a `net_cls` cgroup, use the cgroup to set the class of the packets, and then use a classful filter in `tc` to rate limit packets in that class. For example:

```
cgcreate -g net_cls:slow
echo 0x10001 > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/slow/net_cls.classid
cgclassify -g net_cls:slow <pid of the process you want to limit>
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: handle 1: cgroup
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbps
```

That should then mean that the process you specify (and any of its child processes) are limited to 1 megabyte per second of bandwidth - tweak the parameter to the last command to whatever bandwidth you want.

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to work for me

cgcreate -g net_cls:slow
echo 0x10001 > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/slow/net_cls.classid
cgclassify -g net_cls:slow 25775
tc qdisc add dev wlp3s0 root handle 1: htb
tc filter add dev wlp3s0 parent 1: handle 1: cgroup
tc class add dev wlp3s0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10kbit

Comment: gawd, sorry about comment formatting! I should say, not sure how this would limit download speed, there is no mention of "ingress"?